# beginContact triggered more than once on some objects

Tags: collision-detection, box2d, platformer

Short version: It looks like beginContact is detecting continuous collisions. I'd like to avoid that.

Long version : I use Box2Dweb to write a 2D platformer. It's my first game using this lib, and, to be honest, my first game ever.

I've read almost everything on collision detection (with contactListener), but I must have understood something wrong.

When the game starts, my player is spawned a little above the ground. It falls due to gravity, and an event is triggered **once** when it touches the ground (and my player.canJump property is set to true).

I also added "Bricks" (aka platforms) on the Stage. They are "simple" Polygon shapes (rectangle) attached to staticBodies.

Whenever my player touches a brick, the beginContact event is fired many times, and contact.IsTouching() is true for each instance.

edit: endContact seems to be fired too, the same amount of times.

Here is the (relevant part of the) code that I'm using to instantiate Bricks (it's inside a class "Brick") :

```
var bodyDef = new box2d.b2BodyDef()
bodyDef.type = box2d.b2Body.b2_staticBody;
bodyDef.userData = this;
bodyDef.position.x = x / SCALE;
bodyDef.position.y = y / SCALE;
bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
this.view.body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);

var fixDef = new box2d.b2FixtureDef();
fixDef.density = 1;
fixDef.isSensor = false;
fixDef.friction = 0.5;
fixDef.restitution = 0.2;
fixDef.shape = new box2d.b2PolygonShape();
fixDef.shape.SetAsBox((this.width/2) / SCALE , (this.height/2) / SCALE);
this.view.body.CreateFixture(fixDef);
```

In my init function (called only one), I'm setting up some listeners :

```
var b2Listener = Box2D.Dynamics.b2ContactListener;
var listener = new b2Listener;

listener.BeginContact = function(contact) {
    var userDataA = contact.GetFixtureA().GetUserData() || contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData(); 
    var userDataB = contact.GetFixtureB().GetUserData() || contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetUserData();
    console.log('beginContact fired!');
}
```

If I jump on a platform, the event is triggered multiple times (something like 30). If I fall back on the ground, it's triggered only once (which is what I want).

(If you need to see what's happening, please have a look at the console there : http://www.enpause.com/plates-formes/ )

Could you please correct my mistake ? Thank you very much!